# Logitech M325 wireless mouse, IOGEAR KVM, sticky/useless on Ubuntu Studio 19 with LL kernel (intermittent)

Tags: usb, mouse, logitech

I've just installed Ubuntu Studio (with low latency kernel) on an Athlon X4 740 system that previously ran Ubuntu 14.04 for a number of years, then 18.04 for a little while and now this one because I'm dedicating this box to audio stuff and want to optimize it for that purpose.  So I've used the exact same hardware on other Ubuntu versions without this issue.

I've had this device hooked up to a USB/VGA type IoGear KVM switch along with a Windows 10 machine and a Gigabyte "Brix" system running Ubuntu 16.04. Only with the recently installed Ubuntu Studio on my mini-ITX box am I getting any issue.

I actually suspect the KVM now more than anything else, though why "it used to work" is baffling.  Maybe it's something with the USB ports on the box itself.  Sometimes the keyboard is also not responsive, BUT switch the KVM to either of the other 2 PCs connected to it and all is fine.

a) USB keyboard input (also on the KVM) drops characters if I go too fast, like on double letters.

b) Logitech 325 Mouse (on Unifying receiver) is not fully frozen but barely moves. Wired USB mouse coming through a different USB port is not smooth, but is usable.

SOMETIMES however, when I boot, this does not happen and the wireless mouse and USB keyboard work quickly and smoothly. Right now it's about 1 out of 5 boots is OK.

```
larry@ub-studio:~$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PixArt Microsoft USB Optical Mouse        id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech M325                             id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Microsoft Wired Keyboard 600 Consumer Control id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Microsoft Wired Keyboard 600              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Microsoft Wired Keyboard 600 System Control   id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Microsoft Wired Keyboard 600 Consumer Control id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
larry@ub-studio:~$
```

The result above is when the mouse is misbehaving. I haven't got it behaving recently to compare. When I use the KVM to switch to the Windows or other Ubuntu system it works fine. I haven't yet tried different USB ports on the back but that's next.

```
larry@ub-studio:~$ dmesg | grep -i mouse
[    1.113250] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    2.481843] input: Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:400a Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0005/0003:046D:400A.0006/input/input6
[    2.481986] hid-generic 0003:046D:400A.0006: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:400a] on usb-0000:00:12.0-2:1
[    2.507654] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:400A.0006: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech M325] on usb-0000:00:12.0-2:1
[    3.174538] usb 3-3: Product: Microsoft USB Optical Mouse
[    3.181895] input: PixArt Microsoft USB Optical Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb3/3-3/3-3:1.0/0003:045E:00CB.0007/input/input11
[    3.182216] hid-generic 0003:045E:00CB.0007: input,hidraw4: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [PixArt Microsoft USB Optical Mouse] on usb-0000:00:12.0-3/input0
[ 3439.831928] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:400A.000D: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech M325] on usb-0000:00:12.0-2:1
larry@ub-studio:~$
```

```
larry@ub-studio:~$ dmesg | grep -i logitech
[    2.353461] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: Logitech
[    2.374388] logitech-djreceiver 0003:046D:C52B.0005: hiddev0,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Device [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:12.0-2/input2
[    2.481843] input: Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:400a Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0005/0003:046D:400A.0006/input/input6
[    2.481986] hid-generic 0003:046D:400A.0006: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:400a] on usb-0000:00:12.0-2:1
[    2.507522] input: Logitech M325 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0005/0003:046D:400A.0006/input/input10
[    2.507654] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:400A.0006: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech M325] on usb-0000:00:12.0-2:1
[   48.470347] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:400A.0006: Can not get the protocol version.
[   50.731246] Modules linked in: cmac bnep nls_iso8859_1 nvidia_uvm(POE) snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_pcm nvidia(POE) snd_seq_midi btusb joydev snd_seq_midi_event arc4 snd_rawmidi btrtl input_leds iwlmvm snd_seq edac_mce_amd btbcm btintel snd_seq_device mac80211 bluetooth kvm_amd snd_timer ecdh_generic ccp snd iwlwifi kvm irqbypass soundcore k10temp cfg80211 drm crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel aes_x86_64 crypto_simd cryptd mac_hid glue_helper sch_fq_codel cuse parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj pata_acpi hid_generic usbhid hid i2c_piix4 pata_atiixp r8169 ahci realtek libahci video
[   52.006389] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:400A.0006: HID++ 2.0 device connected.
[  281.963682] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:400A.0006: hidpp20_batterylevel_get_battery_capacity: received protocol error 0x09
[ 2105.769626] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:400A.0006: hidpp20_batterylevel_get_battery_capacity: received protocol error 0x09
[ 2497.141240] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:400A.0006: hidpp20_batterylevel_get_battery_capacity: received protocol error 0x09
[ 3118.252873] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:400A.0006: hidpp20_batterylevel_get_battery_capacity: received protocol error 0x09
[ 3436.919596] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: Logitech
[ 3438.584052] logitech-djreceiver 0003:046D:C52B.000C: hiddev0,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Device [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:12.0-2/input2
[ 3439.831760] input: Logitech M325 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.000C/0003:046D:400A.000D/input/input19
[ 3439.831928] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:400A.000D: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech M325] on usb-0000:00:12.0-2:1
larry@ub-studio:~$
```

[update #1]
I changed the USB cables in the rear where the KVM connects.  It looks like there are USB 1.1, 2.0, and 3.0 ports on this system (going on lsusb).  Previously the keyboard and Logitech receiver were on the 1.1 bus.  Now they are on the 2.0 bus and I rebooted.

Both the wired mouse (whose USB connection did not change) and the wireless mouse worked smoothly after boot.  A few seconds after I logged in, wireless mouse locked up completely, while wired mouse continues to work smoothly.

I think the keyboard is working more smoothly and not dropping characters. tttttttttt should be ten t's.  Yep.

[update #2] rebooted again.  Went into BIOS and turned OFF Legacy USB support.  Back at login prompt, wireless mouse is smooth and wired mouse is jerky!  After login, wireless mouse locks up and wired mouse continues to work although jerky.

Keyboard response.  tttttttttt ten t's looks OK still.

I could switch to wired mouse, at least it works.  Then the question will be, why is it smooth sometimes and jerky most of the time?

Comment: I have that mouse on MATE 19.04. No problem. However I have found that sometimes I need to re-pair my Logitech devices with their receiver. Have you tried that? Unpair, reboot, re-pair.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but if the same mouse and receiver work fine with Windows and another Ubuntu system it's unlikely to be the pairing. Also, I would think if it lost its pairing, that would be it and it wouldn't work at all, not sort of sometimes.  TBH I'm thinking it may have something to do with the USB ports on this motherboard because I'm dropping keyboard characters too if I type too fast.  I will try swapping cables around and see what happens.